# How to simplify (find the product form) derivative $ [\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)]'$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to get the 'product-form' of this polynomial but I cannot seem to get anywhere. I would appreciate any help.

$$ [\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)]'=  \frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{1}{3}[\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)+\frac{6x+2}{x^3+x^2}]$$

I tried common denominator and multiplying everything but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "shape product" mean? I've never heard that phrase.

Comment: some form from which you can find zero values like $(x-2)(x+1)$ so the zero value would be $2$ and $-1$

Comment: I am looking for the derivative.

Comment: I don't think your derivative is taken correctly.  When you take the derivative of the first term $[(x^3+x^2)^{-2/3}]'=-\frac 23(x^3+x^2)^{-5/3}(3x^2+2x)$ which is off the first term on the right by a factor $\frac {3x^2+2x}{(x^3+x^2)^2}$.  I used your derivative in my update.

Comment: You're right. Thanks

Comment: The word you are looking for is *factor*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote: $y=x^3+x^2, y'=3x^2+2x,y''=6x+2$. Then you want to take derivative of:
$$[\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)]'=[\frac{1}{3}y^\frac{-2}{3}\cdot y']'=\\
\frac13\cdot \left(-\frac23\right)y^{-\frac53}y'^2+\frac13y^{-\frac23}y''=\\
-\frac19y^{-\frac53}\left(2y'^2-3yy''\right)=\\
-\frac19y^{-\frac53}\left(\color{blue}{2(3x^2+2x)^2}\color{red}{-3(x^3+x^2)(6x+2)}\right)=\\
-\frac19y^{-\frac53}\left(\color{blue}{18x^4+24x^3+8x^2}\color{red}{-18x^4-6x^3-18x^3-6x^2}\right)=\\
-\frac19y^{-\frac53}\left(2x^2\right)=\\
-\frac{2x^2}{9(x^3+x^2)^{5/3}}.$$
WA [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%201%2F3(x%5E3%2Bx%5E2)%5E(-2%2F3)*(3x%5E2%2B2x)).

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can just factor the things inside the parentheses
$$\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)=\frac{1}{3}(x+1)^\frac{-2}{3}(x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}x(3x+2)$$
Then combine the $x$ terms to get
$$\frac{1}{3}(x+1)^\frac{-2}{3}x^\frac{-1}{3}(3x+2)$$
This identifies the roots as $-\frac 23$ and vertical asymptotes at $-1,0$

Added for the new question, accepting your expression for the derivative.  You need to put the sum over a common denominator
$$\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{1}{3}[\frac{-2}{3}(3x^2+2x)+\frac{6x+2}{x^3+x^2}]=\\
\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{1}{3}[\frac{-2(3x^2+2x)(x^3+x^2)+18x+6}{3x^3+3x^2}]=\\
\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}[-2(3x^2+2x)(x^3+x^2)+18x+6]=\\
\frac{1}{3}(x^3+x^2)^\frac{-2}{3}[-12x^5-10x^4-4x^3+18x+6]$$
And [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20-12x%5E5-10x%5E4-4x%5E3%2B18x%2B6) cannot factor the last.  Not all quintics can be factored in radicals..

Comment: Are $x=-1$ and $x=0$ really roots?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I forgot to add the derivative. It's changed now.

Comment: @Botond:  Thanks.  Fixed

Comment: Are you and farruhota doing the same problem, Ross? It sure looks like you're getting different answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I accepted OPs expression for the derivative and worked from there.  I think OP took the derivative incorrectly and commented on the original post. I believe farruhota took the derivative himself and did it correctly.